# window.location.reload(); is losing viewstate in IE8

Tags: javascript, firefox, internet-explorer-8, viewstate, reload

On Click of a button, I need to make sure window control changes to new new element(tab). Therefore, I am using something like this in html:

```html
<input id="back" type="button" value="Back to Form" onclick="backTo();">
```

and the corresponding JS code is:-

```js
function backTo(){
    window.location.href='#fragment-1';
    window.location.reload();
}
```

On executing above in Firefox, control is going back to the element(fragment-1) with fields having text-data entered prev. While the same in IE8 control is going back to fragment-1 element but all text-data entered prev is lost.

Further, I have added Cache-control paremeter set to public and tried seeing whether this would help the viewstate to be loaded from cache whenever control goest back to given div/element.

Anything missing?

Answer (score 0):

well.. it depends upon how a particular browser saves the state of the page..
also try using history.go() method http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_go.asp and see if the problem is solved.

Comment: I tried history.go() and that is also navigating to new element but still the viewstate(text within textfield) is missing.

Answer (score 0):

how about resubmitting the form instead of reloading:

```
document.forms[0].submit();//assumed there is only one form in you page
```

**UPDATE: This should do it:**
Assuming that div below is the element you like to transfer the control to, use the scrollIntoView function:

```
<div id="fragment-1" name="fragment-1">
....
</div>

document.getElementById('fragment-1').scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: I do not want to post to server but want the control to goto another element within the doc. Since this is tabbed app, on clikcing bakc button, I want to navigate to prev tab without the state being changed.

Comment: I am afraid as this isnt working both in Mozilla and IE8 as well.